# DBT - How to use snowflake COPY INTO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am wondering how do i use Copy Into command in a dbt snowflake settings? And in general i am not sure how to perform functions like creating an empty table like below

```
CREATE OR replace TABLE anaplan_raw.quarterly_cashflow_master_project
(
                                                xx      varchar(100),
                                                yy        varchar(100),
                                                zz         varchar(100),
                                                aa         number(12,2),
                                                bb         number(12,2),
                                                cc       number(12,2),
                                                dd         date
                        );
```

I tried a few way utilizing macro but to no avail.
Thank you very much.

here is my macro and the results

```
{% macro unload_data_to_snowflake() %}

    {{ log("Unloading data", True) }}
    BEGIN;
    COPY INTO anaplan_raw.quarterly_cashflow_master_project
    FROM @my_azure_stage/QuaterlyMasterProjectDDQ.csv
    FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' SKIP_HEADER = 1 field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')
    COMMIT;
    {{ log("Unloaded data", True) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

Results

```
03:49:19  Unloading data
03:49:19  Unloaded data
```

Seems that nothing is being run at all

Answer (score 0):

DBT is specialized on T of the ELT (Extract Load Transform). It assume the data has been loaded to the data warehouse.

Here is a quote from [dbt document](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/Warehouse/loading-data).

> Can dbt be used to load data?
>
> No, dbt does not extract or load data. It focuses on the transformation step only.

It is recommended use other tools to load data into data warehouse first. Though there are couple workaround might be used for limited amount of usecases.

#### Workaround A, dbt seed

dbt seed might be used if just small amount of seed data. It is not recommended for load large data, see dbt document [load-raw-data-with-seed](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/Seeds/load-raw-data-with-seed)

#### Workaround B, snowflake external table

snowflake external data could be potentially used. see snowflake document [Introduction to External Tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro)

#### Recommendation

As dbt recommended, it is best use other tools load data into data warehouse.

Further more snowflake `COPY INTO` has a nice feature that will only load newly added files but not load again to create duplicates.